# Getting error while using the glove vector

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, stanford-nlp, glove

Can anyone please suggest me how to resolve this error. I am simply loading the glove vector and when trying to iterate , it is showing this error

```
embeddings_index = dict()
f = open('/content/drive/My Drive/lstm donor/lstm_glove_vectors')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-3373015fdc0b> in <module>()
      1 embeddings_index = dict()
      2 with open('/content/drive/My Drive/lstm donor/lstm_glove_vectors','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
----> 3   for line in f:
      4           values = line.split()
      5           word = values[0]

/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a decoding Issue, i.e. it can not decode the data that you want to read. If you try to read a csv, add `csv` to your file name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's saying the first byte of the file (position 0) is 0x80, unless that means position 0 at some point during the decoding of an individual character. At any rate, this means it isn't a valid utf-8 file. I don't recognize the name 'lstm_glove_vectors' so someone has trained their own vectors or done something (at least renaming, maybe more processing) to the original distributed vectors. Most likely this file most likely isn't a plain text file. It might be a gzipped or zip file? Or vectors in binary encoding as numbers?

I'd just try looking at the contents with something like the `more` or `less` command and seeing what seems to be there.

Final possibility: The very first release of the Common Crawl-derived GloVe vectors did have a few Unicode errors in them, so this could occur if you're using a very old data file. But that problem was fixed in 2015.